# Atlas inside image.xcassets with different devices

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, xcode7, atlas

Let's suppose I want an atlas for each of those devices: iPhone 4S, iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. What if I create the following schema inside the image.xcassets?

- Tutorial

  - Tutorial-480h.**atlas**

    - background
    - button
  - Tutorial-568h.**atlas**

    - background
    - button
  - Tutorial-667h.**atlas**

    - background
    - button

and

- MainMenu

  - MainMenu-480h.**atlas**

    - background
  - MainMenu-568h.**atlas**

    - background
  - MainMenu-667h.**atlas**

    - background

and put all the images inside the @2x box? Could this work? I mean, do you have any suggestion or better alternatives?